# Is there any chance of this page not loading?

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to use a fade in effect on a website so that when the page finishes loading, it fades in the content.

The reason being is because of some absolute positioned elements loading first things can look a little messy on slower connections until everything has kicked in.

So I've found a bit of code on here that does the job well, here it is:

**HTML**

```
<body id="main-content">
```

**CSS**

```
#main-content { 
    display: none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-content').fadeIn();
});
```

This is pretty much exactly what I want, but my dilemma is this; are there any circumstances that the jQuery won't fire and the body css is still set to display none?

I'm a complete jQuery newb so have no idea if this can happen, I understand it's a remote library so I think it doesn't need to be installed in a browser like Java, but that's about all I know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A browser with js disabled, E.g. a user running noscript would never see anything, so adding a detection for JavaScript support would seem a good idea

Comment: If the user has javascript disabled they will never see the body. But otherwise, you can reasonably expect the fadeIn to work every time.

Comment: _are there any circumstances that the jQuery won't fire and the body css is still set to display none?_ Yes, many: javascript disabled, jQuery lib not loaded, network error, computer is crashed, nuclear war started, world ended...

Comment: @mishik quite funny comment :)

Comment: lol mishik lucky I'm developing locally otherwise we'd all be doomed. Thanks for the answers guys, @Alex K - if you'd like to put that as a proper answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @mishik Or if the computer is destroyed by flying waffles, don't forget about that.

Comment: @mishik the World end could be the solution to get rid of IE6, don't you think?!

Comment: @number8pie accept Ozren's as he has an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing FOUC (flicker of unstyled content).
You could make use of `<noscript>` to protect your page from js-disabled clients:

```
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
#main-content {display: block}
</style>
</noscript>
```

See [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content) discussion as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to make sure everyone sees the page. Just checking though that if I include this in the head of each page where the stylesheets are called, this will over-ride the stylesheet if the person has JavaScript disabled right? -NEVER MIND I tested it and it works, thanks again!

Comment: I can't guarantee this will be bullet-proof, but you can try with `!important`. See [http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Answer (score 0):

people with javascript disabled wont see your page, but those shall rather be a small percentage of all your visitors.

I would create another div with a warning "enable javascript to see this website" and remove this div with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#warning').remove();
    $('#main-content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if JavaScript is disabled then the user won't see your page.

You could do something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id='mainContent> ... </div>
    <noscript> (alternate page for people with JS disabled) </noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3 animations, browsers that don't support will just show the page without the fade in.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }

#main-content {
  /*run the animation only once*/
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; 
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;

  /*Stay at end of animation*/
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  /*Length of animation*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/gpfVJ/